# Difference between reading and parsing an xml file

Tags: c#, xml

What is the Difference between reading and parsing an xml file ? and how can i parse an xml file and read it using C# ?

Comment: Try `XDocument.Parse(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading an XML file simply reads some text into a variable.

Parsing XML turns that document into a useful data structure that you can read from.

There are several different ways to parse an XML document in C#. You can attempt deserializing it into a class structure, you can simply load it into an [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or you could attempt to use LINQ to XML using [`XDocument.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Mr Niessner and i think you mean LINQ to XML not LINQ to SQL

Comment: And, if you transform already parser XML tree to some different representation, like objects/classes. Then is it called "reading" XML tree into objects, or "parsing" XML tree into objects?